# Get object's name field inside a list inside a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

i cant print the 'name' field of a custom object inside a list which is inside a class.

from main i create the object:

```
SC = Shopping_Cart()
cn = input("Give coupon name:")
cid = random.randint(0, 100)
dis = input("Give discount:")
cp = Coupon(cid, cn, dis)
SC.createCoupon(cp)
SC.__repr__()
```

inside Shopping_Cart i have:

```
def __init__(self):
self.cash = 500.0
self.item_list = []
self.coupon_list = []
self.generic_discount = 0

def createCoupon(self, coupon):
    self.coupon_list.append(coupon)

def __repr__(self):
    for i in self.coupon_list:
        print(str(i))
```

and what it prints is:
<**main**.Coupon object at 0x7faf20683e48>

Comment: Create a `__str()__` method for `Coupon`. Right now Python doesn't know how you want a Coupon formatted.

Comment: Your `__repr__` contains an error. It fails to return a string representation of the object.

Comment: `__repr__` should return a string not print something. Also `Coupon` apparently lacks a `__str__` or `__repr__` method.

Comment: thats it , the Coupon class THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a string not print strings in `__repr__`.

In Shopping cart your repr should be something like:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '\n'.join(self.coupon_list)
```

And, I also suggest in `Coupon` making a `__str__` function to format what it prints, this is minimal but up to you:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"ID: {self.cid} | Name: {self.cn} | Discount: {self.dis}"
```